# Nodeclipse + Nodemon dont want to start apps

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse, nodemon

i set in prefences in Node Path C:!NnS\NodeJS!LIBS\nodemon.cmd

nodemod.cmd

```
"%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js" %*
```

error

```
21 Aug 17:12:11 - [33m[nodemon] v0.7.10[0m
21 Aug 17:12:11 - [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs[0m
21 Aug 17:12:11 - [32m[nodemon] watching: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\nodeclipse-NTS-jee-kepler-win64\ws\NodeProject-1[0m
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
21 Aug 17:12:11 - [32m[nodemon] starting node C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\nodeclipse-NTS-jee-kepler-win64\ws\NodeProject-1\hello-world-server.js[0m
21 Aug 17:12:11 - [nodemon] exception in nodemon killing node
```

if i will start "nodemod.cmd app.js" all works

ps.
nodemon plugins for whatch on filechanges and make restart on any changes
https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: What is nodemon? please give link inside question.

Comment: Ready . https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Answer (score 0):

Running node application with node-dev, forever, supervisor, nodemon etc
as of Nodeclipse 0.4.0 is not yet supported, issue #57 https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/57

It is really smart to try enter path to such utils into `Node path` Preferences settings,
but it is not how that setting is meant to be used.

UPDATE (The solution you have mentioned) run app with a wrapper:

Looks like if in main app will be something like this... all will be ok :)

```
spawn("nodemon.cmd", ["main.js"]...
```

and

```
spawn("nodemon",[" --debug ./server.js 80"]...
```

But I personally would prefer to open console with StartExplorer see [Plugins List](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/list)
(right-click project -> StartExplorer -> open shell) 
then `nodemon main`